# SQL Query to group by particular columns and select the first record based on boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need help to write a `SQL` query to group all records for a particular person by the **PersonId**, **LocationId** and **Role** then choose the first IsActive = true record if it exists, otherwise, return the first IsActive = false. The table primary key is the PersonLocationId. There is a bunch of other columns that I also need to return for the result that is not there. Any suggestions?

```
| PersonLocationId | PersonId | LocationId | Role        | IsActive |
| ---------------- | -------- | ---------- | ----------- | -------- |
| 1                | 1        | 222        | StorePerson | True     |
| 2                | 1        | 222        | StorePerson | False    |
| 3                | 1        | 222        | StorePerson | False    |
```

Comment: SQL data is `unordered`, so what do you mean by `the first IsActive = true record `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to number the rows using `ROW_NUMBER()` with the appropriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

Statement:

```
SELECT PersonLocationId, PersonId, LocationId, Role, IsActive
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY PersonId, LocationId, Role
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsActive = 'True' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, PersonLocationId
      ) AS Rn
   FROM (VALUES
      (1, 1, 222, 'StorePerson', 'True'),
      (2, 1, 222, 'StorePerson', 'False'),
      (3, 1, 222, 'StorePerson', 'False'),
      (4, 2, 222, 'StorePerson', 'False'),
      (5, 2, 222, 'StorePerson', 'False')
   ) v (PersonLocationId, PersonId, LocationId, Role, IsActive)
) t
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Result:

```
PersonLocationId PersonId LocationId Role        IsActive
---------------------------------------------------------
1                1        222        StorePerson True
4                2        222        StorePerson False
```